# require field and decimal number validation is not working for EditText in android

Tags: android, validation, numbers, decimal

whenever i submit details without entering price it showing error of unfortunetlly your project has stopped working something like, price has type integer in database. 
Except price all other fields are working fine.

anybody plz help me to get solution........

```
     <EditText android:id="@+id/txtprice"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:numeric="decimal|integer"/>
```

.java

```
private void adddetails() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String catname=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String member=txtname.getText().toString();
    int price=Integer.parseInt(txtprice.getText().toString());
    String price1=txtprice.getText().toString();
    String desc=txtdesc.getText().toString();
    String date=txtdate.getText().toString();

    validation();

    if(txtname.getText().toString().length() == 0||txtdesc.getText().toString().length() == 0|| txtprice.getText().toString().length() == 0||price < 0 || price1==""){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter all details",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{


    long id = dbAdapter.add(catname, member, price, desc, date);
    if (id > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details has addded successfully",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtname.setText("");
        txtprice.setText("");
        txtdesc.setText("");
        txtdate.setText("");

        //categoryList.set(0, "");
        System.out.println(" categoryList.get(0) ****** " + categoryList.get(0));
        categoryList.set(0,  categoryList.get(0));      
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to add new details",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }

}


private void validation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int price=Integer.parseInt(txtprice.getText().toString());
    String price1=txtprice.getText().toString();
    if( txtname.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
        txtname.setError( "Member name is required!" );
    if( txtdesc.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
        txtdesc.setError( "Description is requied!" );
    if( txtdate.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
        txtdate.setError( "select date is required!" );     
    *if( txtprice.getText().toString().length() == 0 || price1.matches("^[0-9]$")==false )
        txtprice.setError( "Expense amount is requied!" );*
    if( price < 0 || price1==""){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "price field ",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat values

Answer (score 0):

Your xml has:

```
android:numeric="decimal|integer"
```

And then your code has:

```
int price = Integer.parseInt(txtprice.getText().toString());
```

Which means that your EditText field allows decimal numbers which will throw errors when trying to parse as Integers.

If the price field in your database is of type integer, you need to change it to be some type of floating point value because integers are whole numbers only and aren't good for storing prices of things (e.g. $1.25).  Also, you should change your xml to have:

```
android:numeric="decimal"
```

and your code to have:

```
double price = Double.parseDouble(txtPrice.getText().toString());
```